# LDAP + Active Directory session not refreshing

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I can't share any code sadly, but I'm having the following problem and maybe someone could help me at least on how to google this exactly (there are a ton of sites but nothing specific)

I have a .NET api that gets the current user by cookies, using LDAP system

**The problem is, when user 1 works and creates requests, sometimes they get saved as by user 2**

I believe I'm having the following problem:

- user 1 connects and works normally
- user 2 connects and LDAP information it's updated to that author
- user 1 sends a request and it's saved as by user 2 **(but just sometimes)**

I don't even know how to search for this, not familiarized with this environment. Maybe I have to **force a session clearance after logging**?

Thanks!

Comment: *".NET api"* - So is this a web service, or a normal website that people visit from a browser?

Comment: @GabrielLuci it is a web service that is called by a site that holds the cookies. Everything is in the same domain

Comment: So a user goes to a website where they are authenticated via LDAP and that website creates a cookie. Then that website then connects to a web service and authenticates to the web service as the user? If I have that right, then how is the authentication between the website and the web service happening?

Comment: @GabrielLuci you got that right! the cookies that are sent are encrypted user+password, so the webservice decrypts them and checks for authenticity, and then in our database some requests are saved with the wrong user name, for example

Comment: Have you verified that the website is sending the correct credentials to the web service? If so, how is the website keeping track of the cookies?

Comment: @GabrielLuci the logic that mantains the cookies is made in an old service (Silverlight), I believe the problem has to do with the cookies being on the same domain, even when having different terminals, as long as user 2 connects to the site that holds the cookies, user 1 will not be registered anymore on the requests.

Being an old technology, the only thing they found to pass the authentication with no login page was to send these cookies via POST to the service

Comment: Are you able to attach a debugger to either application? It just sounds like the wrong cookie is being used when authenticating to the web service.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I can only .NET service side! Could it be that when user 2 logs in their cookies are refreshed so user 1 cookies are replaced with the new values? We don't have unique names for the cookies, the username and password cookies are all the same for every user on the domain